# How to display a feature value in Prestashop?

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I work with Prestashop 1.6.1.7 and I'd like display a feature value of a product within the product list (where you see a list of products) below its name.

We sell garments and in the BO I created a custom feature value (the material of garments, like Cashmere for example) and I'd like to display this value below its name on the product list.

I had added this following code to display the feature value on the product.tpl and it works only there.. I think this variable it's not a "global, public" variable (I just play with PHP, I'm not an expert)

```
{foreach from=$features item=feature}
<tr class="{cycle values="odd,even"}">
{if isset($feature.value)}
<td>{$feature.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</td>
<td>{$feature.value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</td>
{/if}
</tr>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `$product.features` instead of `$features` in your `product-list.tpl` file ?

Something like this :

```
{foreach from=$product.features item=feature}
<tr class="{cycle values="odd,even"}">
{if isset($feature.value)}
<td>{$feature.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</td>
<td>{$feature.value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</td>
{/if}
</tr>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Yes it's correct, can you please let me know how you think abut this solution? Or where this class is written? Regards

Comment: Well,, assuming you're talking about a category page, the `Category` class gets its products by using the `Product::getProductsProperties` (defined in `classes/Product.php`), which uses the `getProductProperties` method in the same file. The ligne regarding the features should be something like `$row['features'] = Product::getFrontFeaturesStatic((int)$id_lang, $row['id_product']);`  (around line 4000). In the end, the function building the features array is `getFrontFeaturesStatic` (around line 4100 in `classes/Product.php`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I've found if you're looking for a solution like me

When you have a feature with a few values, and you want to show something (text, image,...) if the value is selected for that product in your cart, this code works for me :

```
{foreach from=$product.features item=feature}
{if $feature.id_feature_value == VALUE ID}
```

What you want to show here

```
{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want display features in product list for each product, you can use this [module](https://addons.prestashop.com/en/additional-information-product-tab/44588-show-products-features-or-descriptions-in-product-list.html).

Module is working for prestashop versions 1.6.X and 1.7.X
With this module you can also show descriptions in products thumbnails and much more.

Comment: Please don't write link-only answers.